# Load Balancing of RavenDB

Tags: c#, windows-services, ravendb, nosql

Good Morning,

I am using RavenDB installed as `Windows Service` on 2 different servers.

Fail-over behavior is set to: `FailoverBehavior.AllowReadsFromSecondariesAndWritesToSecondaries` and replication (`master => master`) between those servers is enabled as well.

It's all working well in terms of replication.

I would like to Load-balance `RavenDB` now, as I am not sure if connections are using both servers to deal with requests when both servers are up and running.

Is there any difference in terms of Load Balancing due to way of hosting `RavenDB` (`Windows Service, IIS`)

I was also considering setting up a Load Balancer on top of the `RavenDB` boxes, that would let request to be handled by different boxes and rely on replication so the data is consistent in both servers.

I not sure if that's right way of dealing with `RavenDB` though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load Balancing can be set by setting the FailoverBehavior to:

```
FailoverBehavior = FailoverBehavior.AllowReadsFromSecondariesAndWritesToSecondaries
  | FailoverBehavior.ReadFromAllServers;
```

See: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/Csharp/client-api/bundles/how-client-integrates-with-replication-bundle

This has the effect of making the RavenDB client round robin between the two servers.

In RavenDB 3.5, you can even specify required SLAs, so you can always use the faster server.

Comment: Can I ask why Failover behaviour is deciding about load balancing? That seems to be not clear to me, as Fail-over means - that primary server is broken?

Comment: It is the same code that handles failover (the low level networking code that decide which server to hit)